# amp-video-iframe poster vs placeholder

Tags: amp-html

According to `amp-video-iframe` documentation the `poster` attribute is required:
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-video-iframe/?format=websites

But in the official example page:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/amp-video-iframe.html
Google devs use a `placeholder` instead.
Checking the tag validation source code, it seems that both use cases are valid:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-video-iframe/validator-amp-video-iframe.protoascii#L92

Does anyone know if the placeholder use case is allowed or it should be avoided? I cannot find additional information on the documentation

Comment: If it's valid it's valid

Comment: The above information seems to be inconsistent. I'd like to be sure that it will not become invalid in the future before using placeholders in multiple sites. I found also this for other tags: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required - that is a typo on the docs. Wether or not something is `required` is based on wether or not it is considered valid within AMP. The [validator](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/validator) does not care if it is there or not, so it is not required.

source: work on AMP at Google